# IcCube Reporting, Conditional coloring a Row

Tags: adhoc, iccube-reporting

Using IcCube reporting V6, I know how to conditionnaly color cells of a table in a column (or list of columns) depending on their values.

[image]

Is there a way to conditionnally color a complete row depending on it's label ?
For example, I'd like to color the row in red if it's label is "server" or maybe only values for this row.

[image]

I guess the starting point is to use a Cell Renderer of "Ad-Hoc Expression" type, But I don't know how to write it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do so in IcCube 6.2:

### Ad-Hoc Expression

There is possibility to use expression as a filter function to apply whole cell renderer to a cell/row/column

In this specific case you might want to use (it expects exactly **"true"** string):

```
return context.rowLabel() == 'Server' ? 'true' : 'false'
```

**icCube 6.2 (4217)+**

Return value could be **"true"** or **true**:

```
return context.rowLabel() == 'Server'
```

[Demo report](http://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FAd-Hoc%20Expression&ic3demo)

---

### Color Expression

If your only goal to change a background/text color of a selected cell/row/column you might want to use color expression :

```
if(context.rowLabel() == 'Server'){
    return "#f2a2a5"
}

return null
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I will try when 6.2 is available.